# Angular Material Datepicker - way to change output

Tags: angular6, angular-material2

Is there any way to change **output** of `mat datepicker component`? Currently it is date **string** but I need **timestamp**.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the output as `timestamp` by

```
toTimestamp(strDate){
 var datum = Date.parse(strDate);
 return datum/1000;
}

const outputTimeStamp = this.toTimestamp(output)// output is your output from datepicker
```